# GRANT FILE privileges in MySQL

Tags: mysql, csv

Here is the situation we are facing. We have a critical database for which we have a well defined root user as well as a user account which will be used by applications that need to read the database.

However, someone (other than admin) will need to query sections of the database, dump them into CSV file using the following command - SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE 'test.dat' but for this to work the FILE privilege needs to be granted.

However, as I understand from this page - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_file, this will give him the ability to not only dump the results of a query into a CSV file but also (accidentally) take a CSV file and insert it into the database, which is something we want to prevent at all costs.

What can we do? How do we let him use the INTO FILE option but not let him use the LOAD DATA INFILE option?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried, if FILE priv in conjunction with *only* SELECT priv allows write access in database?

Comment: I am sorry, can you elaborate on this? How would I grant such a permission?

Comment: I guess I understand what you mean, now. So, yes, we just realized that the LOAD DATA INFILE part of the FILES privilege will only work if INSERT permission has also been granted. So, that solves the problem. 

Thanks so much.